# Why is my text and div boxes showing in my navbar/hamburger menu rather than the bottom of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

This is my first post here so I apologize if it's in the incorrect format.

I am making a website using HTML, CSS, and a tiny bit of JavaScript; I am creating the home page. In that page I created a hamburger menu, that – when it opens up – you can see the list of "Home," "Contact," "Features," etc. That part is perfectly fine.

I then wanted to add some content boxes underneath the video. My code for that was correct; however, when I went on my site I couldn't see any of the boxes that I had created, but when I opened the hamburger menu I saw that the boxes and text were in there.

How can I make it so that it isn't in the menu and is at the bottom instead? Please help.

I attached an image to show how it looks:

[image: What it looks from my end]

```js
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle')
const showCase = document.querySelector('.showcase')

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuToggle.classList.toggle('active')
  showCase.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.showcase {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.showcase header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url('menu.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle.active {
  background: url('menu.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
}

.showcase video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.showcase.active {
  right: 300px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #03a9f4;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.text small {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.text h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.text a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.text a:hover {
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

.social {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.social li {
  list-style: none;
}

.social li a {
  display: inline-block;
  filter: invert(1);
  margin-right: 20px;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.social li a:hover {
  transform: scale(0.5) translateY(-20px);
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #03a9f4;
}

@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .showcase,
  .showcase header {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .text small {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .text h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

.boxes .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  background: #0a51cc;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px black;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .boxes .container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
  <header>
    <h2 class="logo">Blizzard Notify</h2>
    <div class="toggle"></div>
  </header>

  <video src="snow.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>

  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <div class="text">
    <small>Welcome to Blizzard Notify</small>
    <h1>A discord server.</h1>
    <a href="#">Explore</a>
  </div>

  <ul class="social">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="instagramlogo.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="twitterlogo.png"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<h1 id="features">
  Features
</h1>

<section class="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Detailed Guides</h2>
      <p>Dummy Text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <h2>Raffles</h2>
      <p>Dummy Text for Now.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <h2>Lowkey Flips</h2>
      <p>Dummy Text for now.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried to get rid of the JavaScript, but that didn't help; I also tried to add some space between the elements but nothing happened. I then tried to see if my CSS was wrong, but it all seemed good. I truly don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `position: relative` property to your `.boxes` div could fix the problem because it gives element the position by the normal flow of the document.

In your CSS, you didn't assign anything to your `.boxes` container, so in default it is set to `static`, causing your issue.

```
body{
    overflow-y: "scroll"; (this is optional.)
}
...
.boxes{
     position: relative
}
...
```

Also, I noticed that you use inline `<script>`. For best practices, please make sure it is at the end of your `<body>` for improved performances.

Check codepen for effect.
https://codepen.io/anthonyzhang220/pen/PoEOebw

Comment: I want the features and boxes to be underneath the video, not on the same lines.

Comment: I see. Sorry, you actually mentioned that in your question. Do you want your boxes moving along with the showcase ```div``` too (just underneath the video)?

Comment: I want the boxes just to be underneath the video so that it's technically a completely separate thing. For the video, I just want the headers and hamburger menu showing that's it. And then underneath the video with a regular white background, I would want it to say Features. And then underneath the features would be the boxes.

Comment: Ok, I think I kind of start to understand what you mean. Because in your original question, you said you want those boxes underneath videos and then you said you actually want to see those boxes, it's a bit confusing.  Give me a minute.

Comment: Thank you. Don't mean to confuse you. The animated video part where the snow is falling I just want the text and the hamburger icon. Underneath the video in a regular white background I want the boxes to show and the text features. I want to be able to add more as well. The issue here is that the boxes are showing up in the hamburger icon and not underneath the video in a different section of the page

Comment: Check again and see if this is the layout you want.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you. And yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Can I ask what my error was?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my answer and explain in detail.